# Basics of Vectors

Tags: vectors

I am not sure what the second bearing is for this question.

> In an orienteering race, the first checkpoint is $500~\text{m}$ from the start and on a bearing of $030^{\circ}$. The second checkpoint is $400~\text{m}$ from the first checkpoint and is $600~\text{m}$ from the start. Find, to the nearest degree, the two possible bearings of checkpoint 2 from the start.

I worked out the first bearing and got 71°.

The answers to this question are 71° and 349°

This is my diagram:
[image]

The angle next to 30° (for the first checkpoint) is 53°

Comment: Do you notice anything if you calculate some **sums** of the pertinent bearings? Hint: $349^{\circ}$ is not too far from $360^{\circ}$ ...

Comment: I tried a lot of ways (maybe 2) and I don't seem to be getting the answer. But I don't get how 1 point can have two different bearings from 1 place (hope you get what I mean)

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Draw how the first checkpoint is located on the map. Then think what could be possible locations for the second checkpoint, given the distances.

Comment: In your answer, you turned west after reaching the first checkpoint.  What if you turn east instead?

Comment: I turned east actually, and no it didn't work when I tried going west

Answer (score 1):

I asked another person how to do it and he responded by saying that the 2nd checkpoint can be on the left or right of the first checkpoint. In my diagram, I only found the bearing by putting the second checkpoint on the right of the first.

This is the diagram of how he did it.
[image]